# /usr/bin/ld: i386 architecture of input file `func.o' is incompatible with i386:x86-64 output

Tags: c++, assembly

hello i have been struggling tryna call assembly an function fucntion from my c++ code im getting this error while running the linking command :

```
g++ func.o test.o -o program
/usr/bin/ld: func.o: in function `_start':
func.asm:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `_start'; /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o:(.text+0x0): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: i386 architecture of input file `func.o' is incompatible with i386:x86-64 output
/usr/bin/ld: test.o: in function `main':
test.cpp:(.text+0x32): undefined reference to `calcsum'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

```
#include<stdio.h>
  2 
  3 
  4 extern "C" int calcsum(int a, int b, int c);
  5 
  6 int main(int argc,char* argv[])
  7 {
  8     int a = 10;
  9     int b = 20;
 10     int c = 30;
 11     int sum = calcsum(a,b,c);
 12 
 13     printf("a: %d", a);
 14     printf("b: %d", b);
 15     printf("c: %d", c);
 16     printf("sum: %d", sum);
 17     return 0;
 18 }
 19
```

the assembly function

```
 1 section .text
  2     global _start
  3 _start:
  4 global _calcsum
  5 _calcsum:
  6 
  7     push ebp
  8     mov ebp, esp
  9 
 10     mov eax, [ebp+8]
 11     mov ecx, [ebp+12]
 12     mov edx, [ebp+16]
 13 
 14     add eax, ecx
 15     add eax, edx
 16 
 17     pop ebp
 18     ret
```

,,,,,,, Thanx in advance

Comment: `g++ -m32` if you have 32 bit code.

Comment: Also, obviously don't define an empty `_start` that falls into `_calcsum`.  Let glibc provide the `_start` process entry point that (eventually) calls main.  That's why you got a multiple-definition error.

Answer (score 1):

1. You are re-defining _start in your assembly file.
2. In x86_64 assembly you cannot push 32-bit registers on the stack. Add BITS 32 if you want to stay with 32-bit architecture or add BITS 64 and replace ebp with rbp etc ...
3. Specify architecture. Add -m64 flag for g++ if you're using x86_64 architecture. Add -m32 for x86 architecture.
4. You don't use Windows so you don't have to add the _ prefix to calcsum. Instead of _calcsum, use just calcsum.

Comment: It appears the OP must have correctly built their asm source file with `nasm -felf32`, hence the `i386 architecture of input file 'func.o' is incompatible ...` error when they tried to link it into a 64-bit executable.  That's why this question is not well asked and not a [mcve].  But no, you definitely do *not* want `bits 32`, that just lets you put 32-bit machine code in a 64-bit `.o` and have it confusingly decode wrong at runtime instead of catching the problem at build time.

Comment: Also, no, just replacing the register names like EBP -> RBP wouldn't be sufficient.  x86-64 System V uses a different calling convention (register args) than i386 SysV.